# How do I calculate F-Tests / F Statistics after xtgcause Granger Causality Tests using Panel Data in Stata

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data, stata, granger-causality

I have set up a Granger Causality test using `xtgcause`.

Because I have X panels, I added the option `regress`: `xtgcause varA varB, regress lags(bic)` to output the results for each panel.

Since most papers I have read use the F statistics to output results, e.g. Beyzatlar et al. - 2014 - Granger-causality between transportation and GDP (p.11), I aim to do that as well.

In a normal regression (also in packagage `vargranger`) I could use `test` however since I am using the `xtgcause` package, I am not sure where to start.

Do you have an alternative to do the Granger Panel test, e.g., in `R` or `statsmodels` in Python?

Why are some (panel) Granger tests defined as F statistics and some as chi-squared statistics?

Comment: There is `plm::pgrangertest` in R which was already brought to your attention here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68938756/granger-causality-with-multiple-countries-in-stata-r/68948725#68948725 . The panel Granger statistic by Dumitrescu/Hurlin (2012) is definend on the chisq statistics of the individual granger tests. If you want the individual Ganger test results as F statistics, just run your favorite command for a normal (non-panel) Granger test per individual series, e.g., by `lmtest::grangertest` in R.

Comment: There could be some statistical background in the question but it seems more like a "how to program" question for Stackoverflow. You might be interested in the relation of the F and chisq distribution, see, e.g., here https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/chi-squared-and-f-distributions/

Comment: Yes, I already asked a similar question, which was more of a basic intro for me. I will check out the second link!

Comment: @Helix123 thanks. By using ```lmtest::grangertest``` and ```plm::pgrangertest``` I was able to reconstruct the output of Statas ```xtgcause varA varB, regress``` (on top got the F statistics for each group). However I am now wondering, since ```pgrangertest``` only returns ```z-tilde``` how I can construct F statistic from it.

Comment: Looking at Beyzatlar et al. (2014), their approach to "panel" Granger testing is just reporting F statistics for each observational unit (countries)....they do not construct a composite statistic based on that. Contrary, Dumistrecu/Hurlin (2012)'s panel Granger testing constructs a _composite_ statistic (Ztilde) based on the chisq statistics for each observational unit.

Comment: I turned my comments into an answer incl. some code to convert between the individiual chisq and F statistics in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The panel Granger statistic by Dumitrescu/Hurlin (2012) is definend on the chisq statistics of the individual granger tests. They construct a composite statistic (Ztilde) based on the chisq statistics for each observational unit.

If you want the individual Ganger test results as F statistics, just run your favorite command for a normal (non-panel) Granger test per individual series, e.g., by `lmtest::grangertest` in R.

Actually, for R, `plm::pgrangertest` uses `lmtest::grangertest` internally but with chi-square Granger tests (which in turn is a simple Wald test).

If you want the individual chi-square statistics, `plm::pgrangertest` has them in the slot `indgranger` of the function's return value. These can be turned into F statistics post-hoc.

Building upon the example in `?plm::pgrangertest`:

```r
# R code
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")
(pgrt <- pgrangertest(inv ~ value, data = Grunfeld, order = c(rep(2L, 9), 3L)))
#> 
#>  Panel Granger (Non-)Causality Test (Dumitrescu/Hurlin (2012))
#> 
#> data:  inv ~ value
#> Ztilde = 1.8181, p-value = 0.06905
#> alternative hypothesis: Granger causality for at least one individual
pgrt$indgranger
#>    firm      Chisq     p-value df lag
#> 1     1  1.8255237 0.401414049  2   2
#> 2     2  4.3694800 0.112506980  2   2
#> 3     3  0.7983334 0.670878856  2   2
#> 4     4  3.3069760 0.191381208  2   2
#> 5     5 11.0631807 0.003959687  2   2
#> 6     6 10.8343468 0.004439678  2   2
#> 7     7  1.3410752 0.511433558  2   2
#> 8     8  0.2900525 0.864999607  2   2
#> 9     9  4.4068769 0.110422824  2   2
#> 10   10  4.0173070 0.259601337  3   3
```

You can use the relation of the F and chisq distribution to calucate the individual F tests (see, e.g., here for the relation of the two distributions https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/chi-squared-and-f-distributions/).

Thus, you could do as follows:

```r
# calc. individual F stats from ind. chisq stats
df1 <- pgrt$indgranger$df
pdim <- pdim(plm(inv~value, data = Grunfeld, model = NA))
df2 <- pdim$Tint$Ti - 2* pgrt$indgranger$df - pgrt$indgranger$df  - 1

fstat <- pgrt$indgranger$Chisq / pgrt$indgranger$df
pvals <- pf(fstat, df1 = df1, df2 = df2, lower.tail = FALSE)
(Ftests <- data.frame("F" = fstat, "p-value" = pvals, "df1" = df1, "df2" = df2))
#>            F    p.value df1 df2
#> 1  0.9127618 0.42566360   2  13
#> 2  2.1847400 0.15206087   2  13
#> 3  0.3991667 0.67882631   2  13
#> 4  1.6534880 0.22919466   2  13
#> 5  5.5315903 0.01827415   2  13
#> 6  5.4171734 0.01944512   2  13
#> 7  0.6705376 0.52826356   2  13
#> 8  0.1450262 0.86637971   2  13
#> 9  2.2034384 0.14994991   2  13
#> 10 1.3391023 0.31631301   3  10
```

Looking at Beyzatlar et al. (2014), their approach to "panel" Granger testing seems to be to just report F statistics for each observational unit (countries)....they do not construct a composite statistic based on that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I should've checked how chi-square and F are related. It's unimpressive since my ```df = 1```. I have been looking at the paper by He et al. (2019) and they construct a composite F statistics for regions.